# SQL Server user defined datatypes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes, user-defined-types

Can we create user defined datatypes in SQL server as we do in Oracle. In Oracle we can create user-defined datatypes by combining two columns like

```
CREATE TYPE lineitem AS OBJECT (
        item_name   VARCHAR2(30),
        quantity    NUMBER,
        unit_price  NUMBER(12,2) );
```

Can we do such thing in SQL server??

Comment: Did you try this?   https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGNI_enUS551US551&q=user+defined+types+in+sql+server

Answer (score 0):

Try [User Defined Table type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx) in Sql Server

```
CREATE TYPE lineitem AS TABLE
( 
item_name VARCHAR(30), 
quantity INT, 
unit_price NUMERIC(12, 2) 
);
```

Comment: CREATE TYPE external_person AS OBJECT (
  name        VARCHAR2(30),
  phone       VARCHAR2(20) );


  CREATE TABLE contacts (
  contact     external_person
  date        DATE );


So can we do this in SQL Server??? Like creating types and using them in table??

Comment: @Anurag - No you cannot use it like that. It can be used to pass table as input to user defined procedure or used defined functions or it can also be used as table variable